# How to use a release version of the std runtime library in gcc using -O0

Tags: c++, gcc

I have some code for educational purpose where I intentionally make a standard library function go out of bounds.

```
/usr/src/debug/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:1221: 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::reference 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[](size_type) [with _CharT = 
char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; reference = char&; 
size_type = long unsigned int]: Assertion '__pos <= size()' failed.
```

This check is done in libstdc++, only in the debug version (see `/usr/src/debug/`...). If I compile my code using -O0 it will use the debug stdlibc++ and if I compile using -O1 or -O2 it doesn't. Is there a way to configure gcc to use -O0 and use the release version of the libstdc++

This is on GCC 12.2.0

Comment: cannot reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/49G8Y6oWW

Comment: @appleapple https://godbolt.org/z/YfobsnMra

This needs libstdc++ in release mode to avoid an assert

Comment: @ Cedric Martens yes it doesn't trigger assert?

Comment: It doesn't on godbolt with -O0 but if I use -O0 locally it will trigger an assert. Same GCC version, same flags (it seems) but GCC might be configured differently.

Comment: are you compile with gcc directly? it doesn't seems like the assert is enable by default.

Comment: Yes, using `g++`, `g++ file.cpp -o file` -> asserts (debug), `g++ -O0 file.cpp -o file` -> asserts (debug), `g++ -O1 file.cpp -o file` -> doesn't assert  `g++ -O2 file.cpp -o file` -> doesn't assert

Comment: With `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` (or `-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS`) the assert also triggers on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/cd71Mao7o). So maybe you need to undefine it? Also see [libstdc++ docu](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_macros.html).